# Using the pow()-method in Java

Tags: java, pow

I am writing a program in Java in which the user is supposed input an integer, n.  My program should then create an array where the entries are [1.25^0], [1.25^1], . . ., [1.25^n].  In order to make this work I have attempted to use the pow()-method.  My code for creating the array is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    functionG[i] = pow(1.25, n); }
```

This is, however, giving me the error message:  "the method pow(double, int) is unidentified for the type Functions" (Functions is the name of my class).

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  I am pretty sure I am on the right track, I just need to get the method to work properly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Math.pow(double, double)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29), or statically import `pow` as such:

```
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you just need to call `Math.pow(...)`, as it's a static method in the [`Math`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    functionG[i] = Math.pow(1.25, i); 
}
```

Note that I've changed it to use `i` rather than `n` as the second argument.

You could *also* get your original code to compile using:

```
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
```

in the import statements at the top of your code. See the Java Language Specification, [section 7.5.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.3) for details of how this works.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Yes, of course I should have used i and not n in the second argument.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

that would be because pow is a static method in the Math(java.lang.Math) class. You have to use Math.pow instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem, as others have noted, with importing of Math.pow or explicitly calling it. However, seeing as you're always using integers as your powers, Math.pow() is a fairly expensive call compared to straight multiplication. I would suggest a method like so. It may give you slightly different results, but it should be sufficient.

```
/**
 * Make a double[] that gives you each power of the original
 * value up to a highestPow.
 */
double[] expandedPow(double orig, int highestPow) {

    if(highestPow < 0) return new double[0];
    if(highestPow == 0) return new double[] { 0.0 };
    double[] arr = new double[highestPow + 1];
    arr[0] = 0.0;
    arr[1] = orig;
    for(int n = 2; n < arr.length; n++) {
        arr[n] = arr[n-1] * orig;
    }
    return arr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I made that may help you understand a few things more clearly.

```
// Make it ready for the loop, no point calling Math.pow() every loop - expensive
import static java.lang.Math.pow;

public class MyPattern {

    public void showTree(int treeDepth) {

        // Create local method fields, we try to avoid doing this in loops
        int depth = treeDepth;
        String result = "", sysOutput = "";

        // Look the depth of the tree
        for( int rowPosition = 0 ; rowPosition < depth ; rowPosition++ ) {
            // Reset the row result each time
            result = "";

            // Build up to the centre (Handle the unique centre value here)
            for( int columnPosition = 0 ; columnPosition <= rowPosition ; columnPosition++ )
                result += (int) pow(2, columnPosition) + " ";

            // Build up from after the centre (reason we -1 from the rowPosition)
            for ( int columnPosition = rowPosition - 1 ; columnPosition >= 0 ; columnPosition-- )
                result += (int) pow(2, columnPosition) + " ";

            // Add the row result to the main output string
            sysOutput += result.trim() + "\n";
        }

        // Output only once, much more efficient
        System.out.print( sysOutput );
    }

    // Good practice to put the main method at the end of the methods
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Good practice to Create Object of itself
        MyPattern test = new MyPattern();

        // Call method on object (very clear this way)
        test.showTree(5);
    }
}
```